# Multi-Tenancy with Spring + Hibernate: "SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

In a Spring 3 application, I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy via Hibernate 4's native [MultiTenantConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4661) and [CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4686). I see that [there was a problem with this in Hibernate 4.1.3](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7306), but I'm running 4.1.9 and still getting a similar exception:

```
   Caused by:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.<init>(AbstractSessionImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:963)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:328)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.afflatus.edu.thoth.repository.UserRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c844ce96.getAllUsers(<generated>)
    at com.afflatus.edu.thoth.service.UserService.getAllUsers(UserService.java:29)
    at com.afflatus.edu.thoth.HomeController.hello(HomeController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) enter code here
```

Below is the relevant code. In the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` I've simply wrote some dumb code for now that just returns a new connection every time, and the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` always returns the same ID at this point. Obviously this logic was to be implemented after I managed to get the connections to instantiate.

## config.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.afflatus.edu.thoth.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl">${hibernate.dbm2ddl}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.afflatus.edu.thoth.connection.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.afflatus.edu.thoth.context.MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="autodetectDataSource" value="false" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

## MultiTenantConnectionProvider.java

```
package com.afflatus.edu.thoth.connection;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    private final Map<String, ConnectionProvider> connectionProviders
        = new HashMap<String, ConnectionProvider>();

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {

        System.out.println("barfoo");
        Properties properties = getConnectionProperties();

        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("");

        InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider defaultProvider = new InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider();
        defaultProvider.setDataSource(ds);
        defaultProvider.configure(properties);

        return (ConnectionProvider) defaultProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) {
        System.out.println("foobar");
        Properties properties = getConnectionProperties();

        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test2");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("");

        InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider defaultProvider = new InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider();
        defaultProvider.setDataSource(ds);
        defaultProvider.configure(properties);

        return (ConnectionProvider) defaultProvider;
    }

    private Properties getConnectionProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test");
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.USER, "root");
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.PASS, "");

        return properties;

    }
}
```

## CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.java

```
package com.afflatus.edu.thoth.context;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;

public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return "1";
    }

    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can anybody see anything specifically wrong? This throws an exception as soon as a transaction is opened. It *seems* like the `SessionFactory` isn't opening the Session correctly, or the `Session` is simply ignoring the value returned by the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`, which I believe was the issue in Hibernate 4.1.3; this was supposed to have been resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Foreward: Although I accepted this answer which (will) contains code, please upvote [Darren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932795/449805) if you think this was useful. He's the reason I was able to solve this at all.*

Okay, so here we go....

[As Darren pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932795/449805), this is really an issue with SessionFactory's instantiating a Session improperly. If you were to instantiate the session manually, you have no issue. eg:

```
sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenant).openSession();
```

However, the `@Transactional` annotation causes the SessionFactory to open a session with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, which does not pull the tenant identifier from the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`.

Darren suggested opening the Session manually in the DAO layer, but this means that each DAO method will have a locally scoped transaction. The better place to do this is on the service layer. Each service layer call (ie, `doSomeLogicalTask()`) may call multiple DAO methods. It makes sense that each of these should be bound to the same transaction, as they're logically related.

Furthermore, I didn't like the idea of duplicating code in each service layer method to create and manage a transaction. Instead, I used AOP to wrap each method in my service layer with with the advice to instantiate a new `Session` and handle the transaction. The aspect stores the current `Session` in a `TheadLocal` stack which can be accessed by the DAO layer for querying.

All of this work will allow the interfaces and implementations to stay identical to their bug-fixed counterparts, except one line in the DAO superclass that will get the `Session` from the `ThreadLocal` stack rather than the `SessionFactory`. This can be changed once the bug is fixed.

I will post the code shortly, once I clean it up a little. If anybody sees any problems with this, do feel free to discuss below.

Comment: May I know is this issue fixed in current latest hibernate version.Please share if possible your working code example.

Comment: Tested with Hibernate 4.2.6 it's working now.The issue resolved in this version.

Comment: Can I have your working example please, I am also using same pattern with @Transaction.

Answer (score 18):

Are you using `@Transactional` anywhere in your code (ie mark a service or dao class/method)?
I was running into the same error until I commented out the `@Transactional` in my service class.
I think it's related to the default openSessionInThread behavior of Hibernate 4.

I also have hibernate configured without a custom implementation of the `ConnectionProvider` and `TenantIdentifierResolver`. I'm using the jndi-based approach, setting the **hibernate.connection.datasource** to java://comp/env/jdbc/, and then passing in the name of the jndi resource into my dao methods, which call

`sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenant).openSession();`

I'm still playing around to see if I can get a configuration working with `@Transactional`, but the jndi-based approach with the default session in thread behavior seems to be working now.

Comment: I am using @Transactional, and I think you're spot-on with your theory. Can you provide some code samples of your Jndi solution? I'm going to play around with this today and see if I can get something working.

Comment: I worked up a solution based on your feedback here. I'm not 100% sold on it, but I'm using AOP to wrap my service layer methods with manual transaction handling. This will keep the public interface of my service layer and DAO classes clean. I'm also still utilizing the ConnectionProvider and TenantIdentifierResolver so when this problem gets patched in the future (which I belive is a bug), all my interfaces stay the same and I can just remove the aspect wrapping my service layer. I will post the relevant code soon.

Comment: @Craige did you managed to get this working? can you share the code?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate defines the [`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-database-schema-multitenancy/) interface to help frameworks like Spring or Java EE to allow using the default `Session` instantiation mechanism (be it from an `EntityManagerFactory`).

So, the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` must be set via a configuration property which is exactly where you went wrong because you didn't supply the right fully-qualified class name. The `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` implementation being `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl`, the `hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver` has to be:

```
<prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.afflatus.edu.thoth.context.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl</prop>
```

After you fix this, when the `HibernateTransactionManager` calls `getSessionFactory().openSession()`, Hibernate will use the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` to resolve the tenant identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this might be an older topic, and the answer might be already taken care of. What I noticed is the following:

In your define the class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl:

```
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver
```

But in your config you reference MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl:

```
<prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.afflatus.edu.thoth.context.MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl</prop>
```

Just pointing this out because I did the same mistake today, after that it all worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when my CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver implementation returned null for the resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() method

Answer (score 1):

I used Spring Boot 3.0.1 with Hibernates 6.1.6.Final and I solved this issue by implementing the interface `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`.

```java
@Configuration
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private String tenantId = "default";

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
    }
}
```

"In a real application [the field `currentTenant`] would either use a different scope (like request, for example) or get the value from some other bean that is appropriately scoped".

The original blog post is authored can be found [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/31/how-to-integrate-hibernates-multitenant-feature-with-spring-data-jpa-in-a-spring-boot-application).

The fact that `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` must be implemented is addressed by the author of the blog post as an [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15422) to the hibernate team and may not be required in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to upgrade version of hibernate to last 4.X and use annotation or aspects to start transaction

Comment: 4.1.9 is the latest stable version packaged via Maven. 4.2 is available as a CR, but even with that I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar kind of issue, But not the same, Just posting maybe helpful to someone in future

Error

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory was not configured for multi-tenancy
```

Solution

We need to add what multi-tenancy strategy are we following by adding below to MultiTenantConnectionProvider

```
 public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, this);
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
  }
```